# use a custom keyboard across other apps in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, customization, uikeyboard, accessoryview

I have a question. One thing I know is that I can customise the iOS keyboard, like add a few buttons using accessoryView, in my iOS app. Now what I want to ask here is that is there any way I can create a custom keyboard with my special keys and use that across multiple apps like Facebook or WhatsApp etc? Please do reply Thanks.

Comment: you will be able to do so in iOS8.

Comment: Check [extensibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW1)

Comment: a bit of explanation on this would be appreciated please.

Comment: @A.J. Is this for iOS8 or below? In iOS 8 Apple have allowed developers to develop custom keyboards, but in every other iOS (iOS 7.1 and below) you aren't allowed to do this. You maybe thinking that well Facebook and WhatsApp do this. Well WhatsApp is owned by Facebook so they will have the same code for customizing. Now you might be thinking well they are using a custom keyboard and I just said Apple will not allow this, well when you have a few million to through around you can buy whatever you want. So basically Facebook is an exception, an exception that you will never become.

Comment: Hmm. That was quite a sentence, "Facebook is an exception, an exception that you will never become". Now I'm gonna try my best to be that one exception. And thanks for the details too. :D